# AspMenu Has Different Behavior On Publishing & Non-Publishing Pages

Tags: master-page, navigation, publishing-site

Why would a `<SharePoint:AspMenu>` control behave one way on publishing pages & another way on non-publishing pages?

I have a custom master page on a publishing site. I would like to remove the welcome page link from the top nav. Merely setting `ShowStartingNode="False"` to the `topSiteMap` datasource control wasn't doing it. I found a [blog post](http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/12/05/how-to-hide-sharepoint-2010-root-node-from-the-top-menu/) that said that the `topSiteMap` datasource was getting overridden by a delegate control, so i created my own delegate control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control Sequence="40" 
           Id="TopNavigationDataSource" 
           ControlClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapDataSourceSwitch"
           ControlAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
    <Property Name="ID">topSiteMap</Property>
    <Property Name="SiteMapProvider">GlobalNavigation</Property>
    <Property Name="EnableViewState">false</Property>
    <Property Name="StartFromCurrentNode">false</Property>
    <Property Name="ShowStartingNode">false</Property>
    <Property Name="TreatStartingNodeAsCurrent">false</Property>
    <Property Name="TrimNonCurrentTypes">Heading</Property>
  </Control>
</Elements>
```

That seemed to work, but as you would expect, that shifted all of the elements up one level (i.e. static elements at level 2 are now static elements at level 1, dynamic elements at level 3 are now static elements at level 2). So back in my master page, I set `StaticDisplayLevels="1"` & `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"` on the `TopNavigationMenuV4` AspMenu control.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenuV4" 
                        Runat="server" 
                        EnableViewState="false" 
                        DataSourceID="topSiteMap" 
                        AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>" 
                        UseSimpleRendering="true" 
                        UseSeparateCss="false" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        StaticDisplayLevels="1" 
                        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" 
                        SkipLinkText="" 
                        CssClass="s4-tn"/>


    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" 
                                ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" 
                                Id="topNavigationDelegate">
      <Template_Controls>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" 
                               SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigation" 
                               id="topSiteMap" 
                               runat="server" 
                               EnableViewState="false" 
                               StartFromCurrentNode="true"/>
      </Template_Controls>
    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

That fixed all publishing pages, but it had no affect on any of the non publishing pages (lists, libraries, site settings, etc).

I tried to replace the `<asp:SiteMapDataSource>` control with a `<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSourceSwitch>` control just like the delegate control, but that didn't work. I checked all my page layouts to make sure i wasn't overriding either the `PlaceHolderTopNavBar` or `PlaceHolderHorizontalNav` placeholders.

I am not sure what i am missing. **Why would publishing pages act like `StaticDisplayLevels="1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"` & non publishing pages act like `StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"`?**

Thank you for your time.